# Unable to connect to MongoDB (MongoLabs) via C# client

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

**Question Background:**

I have setup in MongoLabs (mLab - https://mlab.com/) a database and have added a very simple Collection. I am using the MongoDB driver to attempt to connect and work with this collection via the C# 3.2 driver.

**The Issue:**

I am unable to connect to my database via the C# driver with a constant authentication expection, as shown:

> System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode = Primary, TagSets = [] } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/ds048719.mlab.com:48719" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/ds048719.mlab.com:48719", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed: Authentication failed.

**The Code:**

I have tried a number of different ways of trying to authenticate the request. Currently I am trying to simply use the `MongoClient` class, as shown:

```
MongoClient client;

var connectionString = "mongodb://userNameGoesHereRemovedForSO:passwordGoesHereRemovedForSO@ds048555.mlab.com:48719/db";

client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

var database = client.GetDatabase("testDB");

var collection = database.GetCollection<string>("test");
```

**Any help or examples of how I can successfully overcome this authentication issue would be highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I had to hazard a guess, the issue is most likely a firewall issue. You should check the following

- `nslookup` of the host (ds048719.mlab.com) from the C# Application Host
- `ping` of the host (ds048719.mlab.com) from the C# Application Host (might fail, depending on mLab's settings)
- That your IP address is [whitelisted](http://docs.mlab.com/security/#whitelisting-amazon-ec2-security-groups-aws-only)
- Test the connection using the Mongo Shell from the same host where the C# Application is running. mLab has docs [here](http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#credentials).
- Test the connection with a raw `telnet`, eg `telnet ds048719.mlab.com 48719`
- Ensure you are using the correct `authenticationDatabase` (in your example, this is specified by the `/db`), this is usually `admin` but could be your database name if you are on a shared instance.

You can find the docs on connecting with the C# driver in the [MongoDB C# Driver Docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/reference/driver/connecting/). It is important to note the following:

> **The Database Component**
>
> The database component is optional and is used to indicate which database to authenticate against. When the database component is not provided, the “admin” database is used.
>
> `mongodb://host:27017/mydb`
>
> Above, the database by the name of “mydb” is where the credentials are stored for the application.
>
> **NOTE:**
>
> Some drivers utilize the database component to indicate which database to work with by default. The .NET driver, while it parses the database component, does not use the database component for anything other than authentication.

Finally, I would suggest in the future, obfuscate the hostname and port when posting to SO. While security through obscurity alone is a bad policy, it certainly adds a layer of defense for your MongoDB deployment.

Comment: Very useful! I was not adding the DB at the end which is used for the authentication. Because of that my authentication was failing.

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string may be incorrect. You have /db at the end, is "db" the name of your authentication database?

Ensure your authentication database is correct. If it is not you may want to remove it all together and let it fall back to admin

Comment: The C# driver gets a database reference via the `client.GetDatabase` method. The database specified in the connection string is the `authenticationDatabase`

Comment: thanks @PeteGarafano. this little bit of info was what was keeping me from being able to authenticate

Comment: You're questions led me to question which "db" I was trying to connect to. For some odd reason I can only seem to connect to admin, which lets me work with all of my databases, I'm not sure this is what I want, but it works for now. Thanks @pieperu !

Answer (score 1):

Quick workaround : just remove database name from the `url`

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017");

var _db = client.GetDatabase("testDB");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, in my case user wasn't created in database. You can create user by this

```
db.createUser({
      user: "userNameGoesHereRemovedForSO",
      pwd: "passwordGoesHereRemovedForSO",
      roles: ["readWrite", "dbAdmin"]
    });
```