# I couldn't connect my remote mongo database from C# client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I created some sample mongo database in mlab(https://mlab.com/) and they given mongo client connect details. I tried connecting my remote database but I couldn't connect. I have also given the correct credentials.

Here are some screenshots of my code and errors.

[image: My c# code to connect remote database]

[image: Error occurred in the browser]

Comment: This issue could be probably the mongo DB driver mismatch between local and mlab environment. Try restarting the mlab environment service.

Comment: Check your firewall settings http://stackoverflow.com/a/40248731/920557

Comment: The exception says auth failed.

Comment: but using that login credentials only i m accessing remote database local database is connection