# Getting Hangfire to use MongoDB Storage

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, hangfire, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to get Hanfire to use MongoDB storage using the [Hangfire.Mongo](https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/Hangfire.Mongo) NuGet package.

I'm doing the minimal necessary in `Configure()`:

```
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

And this in `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddHangfire(
    config => config.UseMongoStorage("mongodb://myhost:27017"),
    "MyDatabase");
```

I've verified the database exists and the above connection string is correct.

I get this exception:

> Unable to clean up locks on the resource 'Migrate'. System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
>
> CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "**Unspecified**/myhost:27017" }", EndPoint: "**Unspecified**/myhost:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException:
>
> An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: **No such host is known**
>      at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   ...
>      at Hangfire.Mongo.DistributedLock.MongoDistributedLock.Cleanup() [Hangfire.Mongo.DistributedLock.MongoDistributedLock]

The **bold** parts lead me to believe that some information is not set or getting dropped somewhere, but I am not doing anything out of the ordinary. I checked for firewall issues and tried many of the ideas in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40248731/64348) to someone else's similar question.

I've also tried changing the connection string to all of these

- mongodb://myhost:27017/MyDatabase
- mongodb://myhost:27017/?connect=replicaSet
- mongodb://myhost:27017/MyDatabase/?connect=replicaSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I didn't add in my question is that my application is containerized, as is MongoDB on my machine.

I was running the application in debug outside of the container context in Visual Studio. This means it couldn't see the container network and so couldn't connect.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I get the same error when my app is deployed to kubernetes.