# Connect Mongodb with username and password

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have mongodb database with username and password, I am trying to access to it from C#, I'm worjking with MongoDBDriver version 2.9.1 from NuGet, I tried the following code:

```
var client = new MongoClient($"mongodb://usre1:123@localhost/GSCADB");
IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("GSCADB");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("GSCALogs");
int TotalFiles = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList().Count;
```

but this gives the exception:

> Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to MongoDB (MongoLabs) via C# client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248545/unable-to-connect-to-mongodb-mongolabs-via-c-sharp-client)

Comment: @KlausGütter That's not a firewall issue because I was able to acceess the database before adding it username and password, secondly my error it no not timeout.